# Maximum Array Size in C

Tags: c, io, size, message-queue

I wrote a program to read a text file, send all file content to a message queue, and display in the console.  The size of the text files I have is ranged from 30kb to 30mb. Now my program can only read up to 1024 bytes.  What number should I set MAX in order to read all the file contents?  Or is the problem in somewhere else?  Please advise. Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 1024    //1096

//Declare the message structure
struct msgbuf
{
    long type;
    char mtext[MAX];
};


//Main Function
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    key_t key;      //key to be passed to msgget()
    int msgid;      //return value from msgget()
    int len;
    struct msgbuf *mesg;  //*mesg or mesg?
    int msgflg = 0666 | IPC_CREAT;
    int fd;
    char buff[MAX];


    //Initialize a message queue
    //Get the message queue id
    key = ftok("test.c", 1);
    if (key == -1)
    {
        perror("Can't create ftok.");
        exit(1);
    }

    msgid = msgget(key, msgflg);
    if (msgid < 0)
    {
        perror("Cant create message queue");
        exit(1);
    }

    //writer
    //send to the queue
    mesg=(struct msgbuf*)malloc((unsigned)sizeof(struct msgbuf));
    if (mesg == NULL)
    {
        perror("Could not allocate message buffer.");
        exit(1);
    }

    //set up type
    mesg->type = 100;

    //open file
    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

    while (read(fd,buff,sizeof(buff))>0)
    {
        //printf("%s\n", buff);
        strcpy(mesg->mtext,buff);
    }


    if(msgsnd(msgid, mesg, sizeof(mesg->mtext), IPC_NOWAIT) == -1)
    {
        perror("Cant write to message queue");
        exit(1);
    }


    //reader
    int n;

    while ((n=msgrcv(msgid, mesg, sizeof(mesg->mtext), 100, IPC_NOWAIT)) > 0)
    {
        write(1, mesg->mtext, n);
        printf("\n");

    }

    //delete the message queue
    msgctl(msgid,IPC_RMID,NULL);

    close(fd);

}
```

Comment: Why don't You use dynamic memory?

Comment: @JacobPollack I don't see how's that a problem. Also note that mmap / shared memory is also "dynamic memory".

Comment: @Vinska: Can you explain dynamic memory in a little more details? How should I modify my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a buffer the idea is to choose the smallest size that represents the most meaningful amount of data that you want to process. It's common to read in multiples of the word size chunk for the architecture you are building on.

Keep in mind though, it is extremely bad to read in a large amount of bytes and store it on the stack. This will be highly susceptible to stack overrun. If you *must* store it in memory then the biggest space would be the memory pool. There are tricks to getting around this: process a meaningful amount of bytes at a time (not the entire file). This is where the idea of a dynamic array or some other ADT comes into play.

For your specific case of "*reading a file and outputting it to the console*", it is actually much easier than you would think. You can just read one byte at a time until `EOF` and output it to `stdout`. No need for a queue or anything.

**EDIT:** Per your request, an example of my proposed solution:

```
for ( int byte = getchar(); byte != EOF; byte = getchar() ) {
  printf( "%c", byte );
}
```

... and that would be it. Just processing one byte at a time. You would then pipe your text file to the program:

```
./program < textfile.txt
```

Comment: Sorry, I should edit my question. Actually I want to read a file, send the content to a message queue, but I want to check the content in the message queue, that's why I said outputting it to the console. Do you mind to explain it to me what you mean by reading a byte at a time until EOF? I'm very new to this.

Comment: @user2203774, added an example.

Comment: Thank you so much for the example.  Can I ask one more question? How can I send this to a message queue? At the beginning, I thought I should save each character in a buffer, and just copy it to the message queue. But that goes back to the question of the buffer size. For my homework assignment, I need to read the file contents to a message queue.

Comment: @user2203774, if you are *required* to store it memory then I would use a dynamic array. But this is not practical for a real world application. You can still read it one byte at a time and use a dynamic array to store each byte. That implementation is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Reading a large (multiple-megabyte) file into a stack-allocated buffer all at once is a bad idea, since you will get a stack overflow if the buffer exceeds the stack size.  I believe the default stack size is 1 MB on Windows and 8 MB on Linux.  (Does this depend on the compiler?)

Besides, stack arrays have a fixed size (in C89 anyways) so you have to guess how large your largest possible file could be, and then allocate a buffer large enough to accomodate that, which could be quite wasteful.

If you need the file in memory all at once for some reason, you'll want to heap-allocate the buffer using `malloc()`.  However, it might be preferable to operate on small pieces of the file at a time in a fixed-size buffer.  This will allow you to safely allocate the buffer on the stack, and is much more memory-efficient.

Comment: 'default stack size', it depends on the linker, (on Windows, anyway).